# Why Xcode shows warning when use AVAudioPlayer Delegate protocol in appdelegate.h file?

Tags: xcode, avaudioplayer, uiapplicationdelegate

//---------MyAppDelegate.h

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {
```

//---in some other .m file, trying to acess the device token residing in MyAppDelegate ----------

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

// Results in 
// warning: type 'id ' does not conform to the 'AVAudioPlayerDelegate' protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of a type mismatch:
- The UIApplication.delegate property returns an instance of type id
- You are trying to cast this instance into MyAppDelegate which implements the UIApplicationDelegate and the AVAudioPlayerDelegate protocols.
- As the type returned by the delegate property does not match the appDelegate type, you see the warning.